# Improving efficiency of a Fortran to MATLAB operation

Tags: matlab, intel-fortran, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

I am writing to ask for some advice to optimize my Fortran codes.

A Fortran subroutine is running on the Visual Studio 2013, Windows 10. In this program, an m-file of MATLAB is executed first to generate a data-file for the subsequent Fortran codes. It takes some time (varied from a few seconds to ten seconds) for MATLAB to finish its task. There is a risk that the subsequent Fortran codes would start to run before the MATLAB process finishes. I wrote a section of code as follows. It works but is not efficient considering the 15 seconds sleep time. I would like some advice as to improve the efficiency of this operation, in general. Thanks in advance.

```
logical (4)      :: result_matlab  
logical (4)      :: exists
real (kind=dbl),dimension(1000) :: dataoutofmatlab

result_matlab = SYSTEMQQ("directory of matlab\matlab.exe" -nodesktop -nosplash -r "my_mfile")  
INQUIRE (FILE = dataoutofmatlab, EXIST = exists)    % MATLAB generates ‘dataoutofmatlab.dat’  
if (.NOT. exists) then  
    call sleep(15)  
end if

open(2, file = 'dataoutofmatlab.dat', form = 'formatted')   % Fortran codes read ‘dataoutofmaltab.dat’  
do i = 1, 1000  
    read(2,*) dataoutofmatlab(i)  
end do  
close(2)
```

Comment: I have not used Fortran for many years, but I remember calling Matlab from Fortran code and the script waited until Matlab finished. I used something like
CALL SYSTEM ("matlab -wait -nosplash -nodesktop " ... Hope this gives you some cue

Comment: For me, I think it is easier to call your executable in MATLAB. Just forget about calling the MATLAB in Fortran and assume the files are already there. Then, in your MATLAB code, after generating the data-file, you can call your executable as `!my_executable`. Check the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/shell-escape-functions.html).

Comment: Hi Carlos, I added the command '-wait' and it works faster than before. One more question, is it possible to run Matlab in my Fortran codes without opening the Matlab command window even though the command '-nosplash -nodestop' is used a simple window still pops out?

Comment: Looks like your code starts a new instance of MATLAB each time, which is probably slow. This might be worth reading: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/atlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-fortran-applications.html

Comment: @Daniel, the page you sent does not exist. Can you provide a valid link? Thanks.

Comment: A new try: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-fortran-programs.html

Answer (score 0):

You should not use function `SYSTEMQQ`. It is not in the Fortran standard and therefore non-portable. Instead use, `execute_command_line()` with the optional `wait=.true.` argument:

```
call execute_command_line (command [, wait] [, exitstat] [, cmdstat] [, cmdmsg])
```

where the arguments are as follows:

- `command` has intent in and is a scalar default character string containing the command line to be interpreted by the processor.
- `wait` has intent in and is a scalar default logical indicating whether the command should be executed asynchronously (`wait=.false.`), or whether the procedure should wait for it to terminate before returning to the Fortran program (the default).
- `exitstat` has intent inout and is a scalar default integer variable that, unless wait is false, will be assigned the ‘process exit status’ from the command (the meaning of this is also system dependent).
- `cmdstat` has intent out and is a scalar default integer variable that is assigned zero
  if execute_command_line itself executed without error, −1 if the processor does not support command execution, −2 if `wait=.true.` was specified but the processor does not support asynchronous command execution, and a positive value if any other error occurred.
- `cmdmsg` has intent inout and is a scalar default character string that, if cmdstat is
  assigned a positive value, is assigned an explanatory message.

Comment: thanks, and one question does it only apply to Fortran 2008 and later? My Fortran codes were written in Fortran 90.

Comment: It is Fortran 2008. All you need is a compiler that supports Fortran 2008 or minimally, this command. Intel and GNU Fortran compilers both support Fortran 2008 and both are available for free for students, teachers and open-source developers. Others include IBM and Cray compilers, perhaps also PGI and NAG.